# How to make a menuitem invisible in odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo

The following link solves the same problem for odoo 8.

[Odoo: How to inherit menu items (make menu items invisible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964351/odoo-how-to-inherit-menu-items-make-menu-items-invisible)

I tried everything suggested, nothing seems to work.

This defines the menuitem I am trying to hide:

```
<menuitem id="menu_sale_quote_template" action="action_sale_quotation_template" parent="sale.menu_sales_config" sequence="1" name="Quotation Templates" groups="sales_team.group_sale_salesman,sales_team.group_sale_manager"/>
```

It can be found in:

```
/addons/website_quote/views/sale_quote_views.xml
```

As a newbie it is likely that I am missing something fundamental.

To clarify, I am making my own modul and want to overwrite the existing menuitem with my own. I could make a new entry, now the old one(core odoo) just has to disappear.

I'm not allowed to change the odoo core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is update the actions of the menu.
i used to do this kind of logic to override the default groups given
to menus by my own groups.

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="website_quote.menu_sale_quote_template">
    <field name="action" eval="False">
</record>
```

Menu without child or action will not displayed by the framework.

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

> Please add This group in view

```
<record id="hide" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Hide</field>
            <field name="comment">Hide.</field>
        </record>
```

> add this group in quotation menu

```
<menuitem id="sale.menu_sale_quote_template" action="sale.action_sale_quotation_template" parent="sale.menu_sales_config" sequence="1" name="Quotation Templates" groups="hide"/>
```

Comment: This works for changing the odoo core. But I am not allowed to do that. Is there an option to do the same without changing odoo itself.

Comment: To clarify, I am making my own modul and want to overwrite the existing menuitem with my own. I could make a new entry, now the old one(core odoo) just has to disappear.

Comment: Yes you can add this code in your custom module view. It wont change any core code of odoo

Comment: A simple and great solution, no need to even touch or modify or override any core modules. Works perfectly